# How to hide Id in Url in mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My url Is
http://localhost:5003/Inventory/AddExistingProduct?productId=7

But I need url like these..
http://localhost:5003/Inventory/AddExistingProduct

Comment: Where would you want to have the ID then if not in the address?

Comment: use a post instead of a get request

Comment: It would be really nice if you could provide some context, like why do you need to hide the id, how does you code look like etc.